# C++ wrapper code to extract .zip file?

Tags: c++, qt, zlib, compression

I want to unzip the .zip file.
can anyone suggest me good C++ wrapper for it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[QuaZIP - Qt/C++ wrapper for ZIP/UNZIP package](http://quazip.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

Can't go wrong with [zipios++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zipios/)

Comment: It can. My mingw 3.2 didn't compile it.

Answer (score 1):

For Qt/Embedded I have used [libzip](http://www.nih.at/libzip/) which works on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

There are also several answers on this other SO question worth looking at:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518129/qt-classes-to-zip-unzip-files

I haven't used any yet, but have looked carefully at the docs of several, and for handling entire archives of multiple files, it looks like OSDaB provides the easiest solution.